# Azure function forwarding alert

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am thinking to use azure function app to forward the public URL to private vnet URL.
So my function integrated with vnet and since azure alert action on the public domain, I want to send the alert to function URL and the function forward that URL to my private URL which reside inside the vnet.
Not sure if this idea working or not I need some feedback and what I need to do or any solution out there.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as in [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-vnet) using Azure Function Proxies. Other approaches to consider could include Azure Front Door or Azure Application Gateway, depending on the feature set you're looking for.